# Set unicode character width in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am using following UNICODES for designing Emoticons menu on iPad, but I am not able to customise its height.

```
arrayEmoticons=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"\U0001F61D",
                @"\U0001F621",@"\U0001F61C",@"\U0001F47F",@"\U0001F603",
                @"\U0001F60D",@"\U0001F612",@"\U0001F637",@"\U0001F614",
                @"\U0001F60A",@"\U0001F633",@"\U0001F631",@"\U0001F628",
                @"\U0001F609",@"\U0001F601", nil];
```

I need to increase the unicode character Height/Width.

Answer (score 2):

You never change the size of unicode values, instead you need to change the size of textField or textView.

I did same with following code for osx application

```
NSArray *arrayEmoticons=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"\U0001F61D",
                @"\U0001F621",@"\U0001F61C",@"\U0001F47F",@"\U0001F603",
                @"\U0001F60D",@"\U0001F612",@"\U0001F637",@"\U0001F614",
                @"\U0001F60A",@"\U0001F633",@"\U0001F631",@"\U0001F628",
                @"\U0001F609",@"\U0001F601", nil];

NSLog(@"%@",arrayEmoticons);

[self.textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:30.0]];


for (id icon in arrayEmoticons) {
  [self.textView setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",self.textView.string,icon]];
}
```

And got the output quite good as :
[image]

EDIT:

For NSButton:

```
[self.button setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:30.0]]; 
[self.button setTitle:arrayEmoticons[3]];
```

For iOS:

Now I tried with ios, and it worked. You can check the difference for size 5 and 50

```
self.button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:5]; 
self.button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];  
self.button.titleLabel.text=arrayEmoticons[3];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am implementing them on UIButton. I have increased Button font and frame. But It does not work.

please help

Comment: I tried with NSButton and that worked!!! `[self.button setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:30.0]];
    [self.button setTitle:arrayEmoticons[3]];`

Comment: Now I tried with ios, and it worked. You can check the difference for size 5 and 50 `self.button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:5];
    self.button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
    self.button.titleLabel.text=arrayEmoticons[3];`

Comment: Thank you. NSButton is cocoa class and available on MacOS, not iOS. I doing coding for iOS.

Comment: You can see my other comment that is for ios UIButton