# How to save smilies and text together into sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sqlite, uitextview

I was trying to save the smilies with text into sqlite database(TEXT TYPE FIELD) and retrive them back once done.
But I'm facing problem to retrive them back. Its showing some special char in between
e.g. **Hello  how are you**

Now my question is how to retrive and show this in UITextView in proper format i.e smilies+text.

Comment: You have save the unicode value of smilies in database

Comment: First you convert smilies value into unicode. [Check unicode value of smilies](http://www.easyapns.com/blog)

Answer (score 3):

You never save smilies!!!

You can save images or you can save it unicode values like "\U0001F621".

If you save unicode values then easily you can read and display them in your app.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171847/set-unicode-character-width-in-ios/15172015#15172015)

Comment: Hi Anoop, Thanks for responding.. What if a user is selecting the smilies from the keyboard of the iPhone itself(adding emoji keyboard from general settings). Is there any way to find the unicode values of those smilies?

Comment: I already visited that one.. Here I mean do I need to save all those unicodes for smilies...OR IS there any way(the way iPhone picks the unicode for a particular smiley when you start typing) to get the unicode of an smiley.. Because I'm facing problem with the iPhone default keyboard which by default having smilies(around 1000).. so How can I get the unicode which is selected by the user form the same???? As I think it'll become quiet hectic too...

Comment: I am not much into ios specific, so my answer may not be fully correct. As you said you searched for convering emoijicons to unicode and failed. then you need to crate a list/database of all unicode and use it in your app.

Comment: I think you can save directly the string, it will get converted to unicode automatically.

Comment: I've tried that its not working.. its converting them into special characters which not identified by textView...