# Some issues when insert special symbol characters to UILabel?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I insert some special symbol by Edit->Special Characters (Copy Character info and paste to label text) :  ⇧

But I have some problems don't know how to solve:

How to scale size of these symbol? I get only small symbol also try to increase font size,label size.

The default library of Xcode not enough for my App. Is there any better library?

Please introduce some tool to make it if you know!

How to display it programmatically in code?

Thanks!

Comment: have a look here, you may find it [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171847/set-unicode-character-width-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change the size of unicode/special values or texts, instead you need to change the font size of textField or textView.

You can change it as :

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:50];
```

For reference:[Set unicode character width in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171847/set-unicode-character-width-in-ios)